# React - FsLightbox - open image onClick based on ID

Tags: reactjs, lightbox

I am trying to use FsLightbox in my gallery app it is almost working but I cannot figure out how to open image on which I just clicked. It always opens the first one or if I slide to another the FsLightbox remembers the last closed.

Is there any way how to overwrite it, so it opens image I want based of ID.

```
const Gallery = () => {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/gallery/';
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState([]);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [toggler, setToggler] = useState(false);
    const [productIndex, setProductIndex] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const result = await axios(url,);
        setData(result.data)
        result.data.forEach(item => {
            imageUrl.push(item.image)
        })
      }
      fetchData();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((item => 
                <div key={item.id} onClick={() => setProductIndex(item.id)}>
                    <img src={item.image} onClick={() => {setToggler(!toggler)}} />
                </div>
            ))}
            <FsLightbox toggler={toggler} sources={imageUrl} key={productIndex} />
        </div> 
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this is to add sourceIndex={} to the FsLightbox component